# On average, what % of my private key is compromised on the first address re-use, and what exponential effect does it have on security?

Tags: security, address-reuse

Each time we use an address, 50% of your private key is revealed at random.

When 50% of the private key is revealed, a computer would have to do 2^256 computations to crack it, similar to the SHA-256 standard, which is considered cryptographically secure.

Mathematically, what % of my private key is revealed on average after the first key re-use, and in terms of exponents similar to 2^256, what level of computational security do I have now, on average?

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I'm still learning Iota specifications, so take this answer with a grain of salt*

---

We assume that you re-use your key for a transaction that is *new and different from the previous (aka `hash(tx1) != hash(tx2)`)*

**Best case scenario** : only *one* new bit is revealed, leaving **49.8%** of your private key to guess, reducing the computations needed to 2^255.
*(note: the very best case would reveal 0 new bit, but that would mean a collision in the transaction hash, which would be disastrous)*

**Worst case scenario** : all the remaining bits are revealed, leaving **0%** of your private key to guess, thus completely exposing your private key. This has a 1/2^512 chance of happening.

**Average case**: assuming on average half of the bits from the hash will match bits from the private key that were used before, that means only **25%** of the key will be left to guess. Since `512 * 0.25` = 128 bits will need to be discovered for the private key to be cracked, **requiring at most 2^128 computations**.